# Библиотеки для удобного ввода формул и ручного построения графиков

Tags: c#, поиск-библиотек

Доброго времени суток. Стоит задача разработать обучающую компьютерную программу по физике для школьников. В требованиях указано, что в программе должна быть возможность вводить формулы и рисовать графики. Существуют ли готовые для этого библиотеки или придётся этот функционал реализовывать самостоятельно? Планируем разрабатывать на C#.

Comment: Уточните какие графики вы хотите рисовать?

Comment: @FoggyFinder Графики из школьного курса физики. Суть в том, что в программе помимо прочего предполагаются задания, в которых от ученика требуется нарисовать график, и потом этот график будет проверяться на правильность.

Comment: @FoggyFinder Например, построить график некоторой зависимости или нарисовать траекторию движения

Answer (score 1):

Погуглите в сторону `latex`

Под `c#` подойдет библиотека `WPF-Math`

https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math

Еще более обширная библиотека (правда под `python` ) - `SymPy`

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html

Comment: Для Python есть также [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Присмотритесь к [`Oxyplot`](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot) и [`Nplot`](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/index.php)

У первого даже код выложен на GitHub